# Count unique weekdays from timestamp column in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, series

I would like to count how many unique weekdays exist in timestamp. Here's an input and I want output to be 4(since 8/5 and 8/6 are weekends).

```
    captureTime
0   8/1/2017 0:05
1   8/2/2017 0:05
2   8/3/2017 0:05
3   8/4/2017 0:05
4   8/5/2017 0:05
5   8/6/2017 0:05
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`np.is_busday`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.is_busday.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {
    'captureTime':[ '8/1/2017 0:05', '8/2/2017 0:05', '8/3/2017 0:05', 
                    '8/4/2017 0:05', '8/5/2017 0:05', '8/6/2017 0:05']})
df['captureTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['captureTime'])

print(np.is_busday(df['captureTime'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')).sum())
```

prints

```
4
```

---

Above, all business days are counted once.
If you wish to count identical `datetimes` only once, you could use

```
np.is_busday(df['captureTime'].unique().astype('datetime64[D]')).sum()
```

Or, if you wish to remove `datetime`s that have identical `date` components, convert to `datetime64[D]` dtype before calling `np.unique`:

```
np.is_busday(np.unique(df['captureTime'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))).sum()
```

Comment: This is definitely the best. Just 35 µs per loop as against 1.26 ms per loop with my solution.

Comment: If I apply last line of your suggestion, say I have dates from July 17 to August 25th. My expected output is 30 since there are 6 weeks and 5 business days. However, it returns me 180.

Comment: @ejshin1: Please post `df[['captureTime']].to_dict('list')` so we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps a slight more intelligent way to debug this would be to look at 
`np.unique(df['captureTime'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))[:41]`.
There are 40 days between 2017-07-17 and 2017-08-25 (inclusive of the endpoints).
So by pigeon hole princple, if `np.unique` is returning more than 40 items, then at least 2 must fall on the same date. I don't think that is possible, but if it is happening, this is an important first step to understanding the problem. (And if `np.is_busday(...).sum()` is returning 180, then `np.unique` must be returning more than 40 items...)

Comment: The other (perhaps more likely) possibility is that `df['captureTime']` contains dates outside the range 2017-07-17 to 2017-08-25. Looking at `np.unique(df['captureTime'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))[‌​:41]` or `((df['captureTime']<pd.Timestamp('2017-07-17')) | (df['captureTime']>=pd.Timestamp('2017-08-26'))).any()` will show us if that is true.

Answer (score 3):

One way is pandas series.dt.weekday

```
df['captureTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['captureTime'])
np.sum(df['captureTime'].dt.weekday.isin([0,1,2,3,4]))
```

It returns 4

You can use boolean indexing in case you need to capture the dates

```
df[df['captureTime'].dt.weekday.isin([0,1,2,3,4])]

    captureTime
0   2017-08-01 00:05:00
1   2017-08-02 00:05:00
2   2017-08-03 00:05:00
3   2017-08-04 00:05:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to date time using `pd.to_datetime`, get the unique dayofweek list, and count all those under 5.

```
out = (df.captureTime.apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.dayofweek.unique() < 5).sum()
print(out)

4
```

`df.unique` removes duplicates, leaving you with a unique array of `daysofweek`, on which count occurrences under `5` (`0 - 4` -> weekdays).

---

Output of `df.dayofweek`:

```
out = df.captureTime.apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.dayofweek
print(out)

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: captureTime, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Using <5 is an interesting approach. +1

Comment: @Vaishali Thanks, `dt.weekday` is a nifty approach too.

Comment: @ejshin1 Well if nothing else, at least I've got that :p

Comment: @Alexander I believe that's what OP wanted. "Count unique weekdays..."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have captureTime as datetime object you can do this,

`s = df['captureTime'].dt.weekday
s[s >= 5].count() # 5, 6 corresponds to saturday, sunday`